# Perp Hilbert space:

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

Let $H$ be an inner product space and $M^\perp =\{x\in H|x\perp M\}$.

trivially $M^\perp$ is a close subspace of $H$ and $M\subseteq M^{\perp\perp}$

also $(M^\perp)^\perp=\overline{M}$.

i.e $M= M^{\perp\perp}$ if and only if  $M$ is closed.

But in generally is the equality $M^\perp= M^{\perp\perp\perp}$  true?

Comment: Please read the tag descriptions and use them appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

In pre-Hilbert spaces it doesn't work that $M^{\perp\perp}=M$ for closed subspaces: take the pre-Hilbert space $l^2_c$ consisting of sequences of finite support $l^2$. Let $X\in l^2_c$ given by $X=(1,1/2,1/3,\cdots)$. If you take $M=\{X\}^\perp$, then $M$ is closed, $M\neq H$ (since $X\notin M$) and $M^{\perp\perp}=H$ (prove it!).

Comment: so the condition M is closed is essentialy?..............

Comment: @b.ba : The example given here is one where (a) $M$ is closed and (b) $M \ne \ell^2_c$ and (b) $M^{\perp}=\{0\}$. Therefore $M^{\perp\perp}=\ell^2_c \ne M$.

Answer (score 0):

If $(M^\perp)^\perp = \overline{M}$ it follows that $((M^\perp)^\perp)^\perp = (\overline{M})^\perp$. It is clear that $(\overline{M})^\perp \subseteq M^\perp$ because $M \subseteq \overline{M}$. If on the other hand $x \in M^\perp$ and $y \in \overline{M}$ then there exists a sequence $(y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $M$ with $y_n \to y$, which is why $\langle x,y \rangle = \lim_{n \to \infty} \langle x,y_n \rangle = 0$.  Thus $x \in (\overline{M})^\perp$ and the direction $M^\perp \subseteq (\overline{M})^\perp$ follows.

Comment: goooooooooooooooooood.